# Is "" & oRecordset.Fields(....).Value the same as Trim$(oRecordset.Fields(....).Value)

Tags: build, vb6, out-of-memory

I am trying to cure an Out Of Memory error that I get when I compile the exe.  After looking into the issue I have found that a good place to start is to replace the strings with constants e.g. change strName = "name" to be strName = SOME_CONSTANT_DECLARED_FURTHER_UP.

Searching through the code I keep coming across code similar to this:

```
strVariable = "" & oRecordset.Fields(COLUMN_NAME).Value
```

I think that the developer was trying to convert the value from the recordset to be a string.  If that is the case then can I change it to be

```
strVariable = Trim$(oRecorset.Fields(COLUMN_NAME).Value)
or
strVariable = CStr(oRecordset.Fields(COLUMN_NAME).Value)
```

Both of these are going to convert it to a string with the former removing any spaces.  I would ask the developer what they were thinking but they are no longer here.

What I need to know is, is there something that VB is doing using what is currently there that it won't do with one of the other options?

This is all through the code so I don't want to go and change it only to find that it's all messed up and I need to change it back again.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `strVariable = "" & oRecordset...` was a way in VB6 to account for Null.  The result is always either an empty string or the data read, not vbNull which made it simpler to test. Your `Trim` and `CStr` may crash when they run into a null value (cant recall).  It short circuited the need for an IF either when assigning the var or using it (null <> empty string)

Comment: Does it look like it runs out of memory? If you watch it in the task manager does it use a lot of memory?